# How do I draw such data structure graphs with visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio

[image]

Is visio able to draw such graphs in the first place?

It seems that the memory objects it can draw is very limited...

The version I used is 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Visio has these shapes out of the box.

However, you can easily use an Array or Stack/Heap (from the Memory Objects section) and add a simple box on top of the structure.

Comment: Thanks!But is there a better way to draw the box then just put it on top of the structure? I want the box and the structure to be sticky so that they're always aligned and I can always resize them as a whole.

Comment: Grouping will achieve this